# Can't get caret position with window.getSelection() on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, emoji, caret

I'm working with React `v17` and `emoji-mart: ^3.0.1`.

- I can pick the emojis and log it out but it fails when trying to insert/display the emojis in the `ContentEditable` component.
- The Emojis that got picked are **displayed normally on Chrome** but don't display anything at all on **Safari** - both mobile and desktop.
- It seems like window.getSelection() method doesn't work on Safari, so the `saveCaretPosition` function doesn't work. That's why the `insertEmoji` function couldn't add the Emoji in the `Editor`.

-> Is there any workaround of `window.getSelection()` for Safari?

---

#### Issue was found on:

- macOS Big Sur 11.4: Safari (Version 14.1.1)
- iPad iOS 13.1.3: Safari

---

#### Demo + Screenshots:

1. Chrome + console

[image: chrome]
[image: chrome console]

2. Safari + console

[image: safari]
[image: safari console]

---

#### The code:

**EmojiPicker.tsx**

```
  const EmojiPicker = ({ onSelectEmoji }: Props) => {
   const control = useVisibilityControl()

   const handleClickOnEmoji = (emoji: BaseEmoji) => {
     control.hide()
     onSelectEmoji(emoji)
     console.log(emoji) // -> Logs the payload successfully!
   }

  return (
    <div className='editor__header'>
      <Popover
        control={control}
        position='absolute'
        className='z-5'
        trigger={
          <div>
            <Icon
              name='emoji-button'
              size={23}
            />
          </div>
        }
        placement={'bottom-right'}
        disableScrollOnVisible>
        <Picker
          onClick={handleClickOnEmoji}
          showSkinTones={false}
          color='#F1B700'
          showPreview={false}
        />
      </Popover>
    </div>
  )}
```

**RangeUtils.ts**

```
const getCaretPosition = () => {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    const sel = window.getSelection()
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      return sel.getRangeAt(0)
    }
  }
  return null
}
```

**Editor.tsx**

```
let savedRange: Range

const Editor = ({ placeholders }: Props) => {

  const editorRef = useRef(null)
  const tributeRef = useRef<Tribute<TemplatePlaceholder>>()


  useEffect(() => {
    const editorElm = editorRef.current
    if (!editorElm) return undefined

    if (placeholders && !tributeRef.current) {
      initTribute(editorElm)
    }

    return () => {
      if (tributeRef.current) {
        tributeRef.current.detach(editorElm)
        tributeRef.current = null
      }
    }
  }, [placeholders, initTribute])

 
  const saveCaretPosition = () => {
    savedRange = RangeUtils.getCaretPosition()
  }

  const insertEmoji = (emoji: BaseEmoji) => {
    console.log(isValidCaret()) // -> Logs 'undefined' on Safari, 'true' on Chrome
    if (!isValidCaret()) {
      console.log('bugsssss') // -> Error only caught on Safari
      return
    }
    
    console.log('emoji selected successfully')
    RangeUtils.restoreCaretPosition(savedRange)
    setTimeout(() => {
      savedRange = RangeUtils.insertTextAtCaret(savedRange, emoji.native)
      onChange(editorRef.current.innerHTML)
    }, 0)
  }

  const isValidCaret = () => {
    const startContainer = savedRange?.startContainer as HTMLElement
    return startContainer?.isContentEditable || startContainer?.parentElement?.isContentEditable
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className='editor__wrapper editor'>
      
        <EmojiPicker onSelectEmoji={insertEmoji} />

        <div className='editor__content'>
          <ContentEditable
            innerRef={editorRef}
            html={value || ''}
            onKeyDown={event => {
              if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                document.execCommand('insertLineBreak')
                event.preventDefault()
              }
            }}
            onChange={(event: ContentEditableEvent) => {
              onChange(event.target.value)
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
              saveCaretPosition()
              onBlur()
            }}
            onPaste={handlePaste}
            spellCheck={false}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: May be you  can check more details in github issues [here](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart/issues)

Comment: @AmanSadhwani Thank you for the suggestion. I tried looking on Github Issues first but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can save `lastEditRange` with `onClick` and `onKeyUp` event in the `ContentEditable`. When adding an emoji node, first recover the range.

```
let selection = getSelection();

lastEditRange = selection.getRangeAt(0);
```

```
let sel = window.getSelection();

if (lastEditRange) {
     sel.removeAllRanges();
     sel.addRange(lastEditRange);
}
```

```
const pasteHtmlAtCaret = (html, lastEditRange) => {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    // IE9 and non-IE
    sel = window.getSelection();
   
    if (lastEditRange) {
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(lastEditRange);
    }
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      var el = document.createElement("div");
      el.innerHTML = html;
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        node,
        lastNode;
      while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
        lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
      }
      range.insertNode(frag);
      // Preserve the selection
      if (lastNode) {
        range = range.cloneRange();
        range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    // IE < 9
    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
  }
};
```